# How to pass authorization code from JSP to Servlet

Tags: authentication, facebook-authentication

I am at my wits end, 7 hours and counting.

I am new to FB development and am having an issue of passing the authorization code from my JSP to my Servlet.

**1.) I use the social plugin for login in my JSP as shown below**

```
<fb:login-button>Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

This logs the user in and allows them to grant my app access to their personal information

**2.) Once login and authorization are successful, the user is forwarded to my servlet from the JSP via the code below**

```
 FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {
 window.location = "testservlet"; 
 });
```

**3.) But when I attempt to get the authorization code (so that I can get the auth. token) in my Servlet, the "code" is empty, see the code I am using to retrieve below**

```
String authCode = req.getParameter("code");
```

**Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?** I am sure that I am missing something so simple..or am trying to do more than is necessary, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Facebook dev, but concerning servlets, window.location normally speaking will not take you to a servlet.
try using jquery's ajax function and pass a "code" parameter. Do something like :

```
$.ajax({
        url: yourServletPath+"testservlet",
        data:"code="+codevariable,
        dataType: "whatever data type your servlet returns",
        success: function(response) 
        {
          // wtv code to be done
        } 
      });
```